# Get customer_logged_in value from http_context

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in. But the problem is in my code eventhough I already logged out it's still check and output that the user is still logged in. Below is my code

```
<?php
namespace Tcm\Goodgifts\Helper;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->context = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        var_dump($this->context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH));

        var_dump($this->customerSession);

        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

So basically if I run the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` the correct output is being displayed. But after I log out or login it retains the old state and not the new one. When I outputted the value of `$this->context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)` it give me this

[image]
[image]

So as you can see it somehow get the value under `_httpContext->data["customer_logged_in"]` but when checking the value I think the correct value should be the one under the `_httpContext->default["customer_logged_in"]` but I don't know how to get this value.

Just by running `$this->context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)` will retrieve the object `Data` and not the `Default`.

Any idea how to get this value? I'm guessing the `Default` note returns the correct/updated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort of half answered your question

When fullpage cache enable generic session class will not work as you expected

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/279788/70343

Comment: Ok so what will be he solution? Aside from disabling the fullpage cache which is not an option for me right now

Comment: @MadzQuestioning did you see this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305070/70343

Comment: Yeah this actually solved my problem. Although I had trouble thinking about how to bind the `Customer` since I don't know Knockout js. But when I looked at the header.phtml of magento theme I was able to fix it. Thanks for the help